# OS X open URL scheme in background

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I'm currently writing an OS X application that implements a custom URL scheme. By design, my app will relatively frequently (about every 2-4 minutes) be opening URLs from an external source. However, this needs to be done in the background (i.e. no GUI or switching of active applications). This is a status bar app (`Application is agent (UIElement)` set to `YES`), and has `Application UI Presentation Mode` set to `All Suppressed`. While these do prevent any UI elements from being shown upon opening a relevant URL, whatever application window that is active at the time loses focus. Obviously, losing focus on whatever window you're working in every few minutes is a no-go, so how can I prevent this behavior when opening custom URLs?

Comment: what API's are you opening URL's from an external source ?  it sounds like you might be using an API that really wants to bring up it's own window or view.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I'm opening it through a URL entered into the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. If anyone else ever runs into this problem:

I removed the `Application UI Presentation Mode` and `Application is agent (UIElement)` keys from the plist. I set `Application is background only` to `YES`. That did the trick. Now the current window no longer loses focus when opening the URL.